# Behaviour subject value is empty when trying to fetch from a second component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I am trying to share data between two components in Angular 8 using BehaviourSubject and a shared service. The code in component 1 is shown below.

```
constructor(private appSharedService: AppSharedService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.appSharedService.getCars()
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.cars = response;
    this.appSharedService.updateCarsList(this.cars);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

The code in the shared app-shared service is

```
export class AppSharedService {

carsSubject : BehaviorSubject<Car[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Car[]>([]);

cars: Observable<Car[]>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getCars (): Observable<Car[]> {
  if (!this.cars) {
    this.cars = this.http.get<Car[]>('url', headers)
    .pipe(
        map( response => response),
        publishReplay(1), // caching the response
        refCount()        
    );
  }
   return this.cars;
 }

 updateCarsList(cars : Car[]) : void{
   this.carsSubject.next(cars);
 }

 getCarsList(): Observable<Car[]>{
   return this.carsSubject.asObservable();
 }
}
```

So I am initially making an API call to fetch data and then caching it so I don't make further API calls. After getting the data in component 1, I call this.appSharedService.updateCarsList(this.cars) to update this.carsSubject value in the shared service. Now I am trying to access this updated value in the component 2 as shown below. The code in component 2 is

```
this.appSharedService.getCarsList()
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.cars = response; // response is always empty
  }, error => {
    this.handleError(error);
  });
```

The problem is the response value I am getting in above component 2 is always empty. I don't understand why I can't get updated BehaviourSubject value in component 2. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Can you try with; this.appSharedService.carsSubject.subscribe()

Comment: Try changing `getCarsList(): Observable<Car[]>` to `get getCarsList(): Observable<Car[]>`?

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud: But carsSubject is a BehaviourSubject and not an observable

Comment: @Jesse: I tried but it shows an error in the component

Comment: Can you please try to add this.appSharedService.carsSubject.value after this.cars = response and try to see what value has in it while debugging it?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi: I tried but it is same empty array value

Comment: @Manzurul: I din't understand. Do you want me to put getCars() method inside the constructor of shared service but that is not possible right?

Comment: No I mean the just subscribe the carsSubject inside constructor like this 
this.carsSubject.subscribe(cars => {
   this.cars = cars;
  });

Comment: Mh, that's strange. Are you providing this service in more than one module? Also, can you put a breakpoint in the cosntructor of this service to see how many times it gets triggered? It should be just one.

Comment: this structure is fairly convoluted but looks fine.... how are you providing this?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi: Wow that was great thinking. I am injecting the service in both individual modules instead of doing it in the main app module. Thank you so much. It is fixed now :)

Comment: Glad it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Change getCarsList() to:

```
getCarsList(){
    return this.carsSubject.getValue();
}
```

and then just call it:

```
this.cars = this.appSharedService.getCarsList();
```

**EDIT**

Could you try setting your carsSubject in getCars() and subscribing to the value in your component to see if it works?

```
    getCars () {
      if (!this.cars) {
         this.cars = this.http.get<Car[]>('url', headers)
         .pipe(
               map( response => response),
               publishReplay(1), // caching the response
               refCount()        
         );
         this.carsSubject.next(this.cars);
      }
    }
```

And in the constructor in your component:

```
this.appSharedService.carsSubject.subscribe(cars => {
    console.log(cars);
});
```

Comment: Have you checked that your getCars() method is returning the cars? A BehaviourSubject is not an Observable so it's probably not returning the cars so when you do updateCarsList with the return of getCars() its not setting carsSubject to anything.

Maybe do something like:

updateCars(){
 this.cars = this.http.get<Car[]>('url', headers)
    .pipe(
        map( response => response),
        publishReplay(1), // caching the response
        refCount()        
    );
this.carsSubject.next(this.cars);
}

getCars(){
return this.carsSubject.getValue();
}

Comment: I checked it many times and the getCars() is returning the data. That is the reason I am using an internal observable to return cars and then calling updateCarsList from component 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your BehaviorSubject as an observable and subscribe to that:

```
private readonly carsSubject: BehaviorSubject<Car[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Car[]>([]);
public readonly $carsObservable: Observable<Car[]> = this.carsSubject.asObservable();
```

Then subscribe to $carsObservable

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a subscribe of getCars() because it returns an observable ones you get the result from the API save the values into the behavior subject that means that you dont need `cars: Observable<Car[]>`; this is you principal error because you can not save values like that. I will modify the code

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.appSharedService.getCars()
    .subscribe(response => {    
      this.appSharedService.updateCarsList(response);
    }, error => {
       console.log(error);
    });
}  

getCars (): Observable<Car[]> {
   if (this.carsSubject.getValue().length <= 0) {
     return this.http.get<Car[]>('url', headers)
     .pipe(
         map( response => response),
         publishReplay(1), // caching the response
         refCount()        
     );
   }
   return this.carsSubject.asObservable();   
 }
```

With this modification you will handle the behavior subject as Cache too.
When ever you call the API it will checks first if the behavior subject is empty if yes it will fetch the data from the server if not it will return the same behavior subject as observable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**AppSharedService**

```
export class AppSharedService implements OnInit {

private carsSubject : BehaviorSubject<Car[]>;
public carsList$(): Observable<Car[]>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.carsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Car[]>([]);
  this.carsList$ = this.carsSubject.asObservable();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.http.get<Car[]>('url', headers).pipe(first()).subscribe(
     (cars) => {
       this.carsSubject.next(cars);
     }
  );
}

 updateCarsList(cars : Car[]) : void{
   this.carsSubject.next(cars);
 }
}
```

Then in your components you have to do:

```
this.appSharedService.carsList$
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.cars = response;
  }, error => {
    this.handleError(error);
  });
```

Let's explain what I did in the AppSharedService.
when the AppSharedService is instantiated you are going to do the http request and save the value in the BehaviorSubject. 
Then when the components subscribe to the carsList$, if the http request was already done they are going to receive the value stored in the BehaviorSubject, on the other hand if the http request wasn't completed yet they will receive the cars list when the http request will complete.