# Angular - BehaviorSubject from sharedService is empty in Component after page reload

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I am creating an Angular 9 app. I have a shared service, which I am using to share user data between my components. It's working correct until I reload the app.

My sharedService is called UserService. The service sets the value of the BehaviorSubject. On login it calls the method *setLoggedInUser()* to get the userID from a JWT, which is stored in another BehaviorSubject in the *AuthenticationService*. Then the data of the user is requested via HTTP call. The value is set to *loggedInUser*:

```
export class UserService {

  public loggedInUser: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.setLoggedInUser();
  }

  async setLoggedInUser() {
    const userID: string = await this.authenticationService.userID.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
    const user: User = await this.getUserByID(userID).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
    this.loggedInUser.next(user);
  }

  getUserByID(id: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }
}
```

In my component I call the user data on init:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.userService.loggedInUser.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => {
    console.log(user);
   });
}
```

On reload the constructor of the UserService calls the *setLoggedInUser()* method to get the user. The userID and the user data are received correctly, but the *ngOnInit* method from the component is called before *this.loggedInUser.next(user)* is called from *setLoggedInUser*. That's why I receive *null* in my component.

I also tried to call *setLoggedInUser()* from my *app.component* instead calling it from the constructor of the *UserService*:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.userService.setLoggedInUser();
    const user = await this.UserService.loggedInUser.toPromise();
    console.log(user);
  }

}
```

But this shows me also *null*. It's still the same problem as before.

Another method I tried without an effect is to pass the BehaviourSubject as Observable as metioned here:
[Behaviour subject value is empty when trying to fetch from a second component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976737/behaviour-subject-value-is-empty-when-trying-to-fetch-from-a-second-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to get one value from `loggedInUser` (thus you use `take(1)`), but when you reload the app the first value you get is the one you use to initialize the `BehaviorSubject`.

To wait until the user is defined before getting it you could add a `filter` operator like this:

```
this.userService.loggedInUser
  .pipe(
    filter(user => user !== null),
    take(1)
  ).subscribe(user => {
    console.log(user);
   });
```

Comment: This works. Maybe it could be annoying to do the null check but for my purposes it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is happening because you are using **BehaviourSubject**. ***The BehaviorSubject has the characteristic that it stores the “current” value. This means that you can always directly get the last emitted value from the BehaviorSubject***.

You initialize the service with `public loggedInUser: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);`

After initializing it with **null** value, when you call **subscribe** on it, it will immediately emit the last value. In your case it is **null** and that's why you receive emit before `this.loggedInUser.next(user)`.

#### Solution

You use **subject** (rather than using **BehaviourSubject**) if your intention is not to get last stored value.

**OR**

I'm not sure but with **BehaviourSubject**, you can keep **behaviourSubject** constructor **empty** instead of **null** and check if it gives you expected result.

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` will still emit when someone subscribes on it and It should always have an initial value

Comment: yeah but in that case emitted value will be empty. isn't it ? And, so I suggested to use `Subject`.

Comment: I can't keep the **BehaviourSubject** empty, it must contain a value. With **Subject** it prints the user value. But I have two problems.
First when I do multiple calls to the **Subject** it stop at the second call and the rest of the code won't be executed. Example:
const user = await this.userService.loggedInUser.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
But I solved it by creating a varaible which is used in the whole component.
Second problem is, that it only works on reload now. When I log in, the login method calls _setLoggedInUser_ and I navigate to my component nothing happens. Nothing is logged.